# MVC convention rules - model binding - theory

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I'm working on a MVC 3 project. So far, I'm using model (@model) binding  to populate items on a razor grid. I had to do some head scratching. From the grid, i select one person using a jquery click event. under the grid, all pertinent information for that row will appear. ie, selecting a person's name. Under the grid, a div becomes visible and displays all sorts of information about that person - name, address etc.

However, I used jquery, $.ajax, loadJSON to populate the HTML controls in that very div. I called the action controller called public JsonResult GetCurrentUser(string p_userid). Now all of this works just great but left me worried - am I doing the right thing?

For the grid, I'm using the model binding to bind the grid (@model) on the cshmtl page but I'm using jquery to populate the div - granted, I still use the model in the JsonResult action to populate the div.

My question is this - theoretically from a design stand point, is this a good practice? By using jquery, the page does not refresh - the grid remains intact while I select various users...works great but I just can't help wonder if I'm breaking model binding convention.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, it sounds OK. You're using jQuery AJAX to perform a GET request to fetch some HTML (which your MVC 3 Razor generates) and then embed that into the page, potentially replacing some content. You're also binding using `@model` which, Jesus *effing* Christ, I've seen my share of developers **not** use when they should.

Of course, depending on the framework (and how strict you're following it), you *might* be clashing against some principles, but if you ask me, what you're doing as it is is fine. It sounds like a solution I'd write to solve a use-case to:

1. Load user details without reloading a page
2. Without loading ALL user details in the initial page load.

Whatever framework you're using, it's most probably going to go along those lines anyway.

Now, code quality and efficiency: that's a different beast altogether. You might be doing the right thing, but not in the right manner. If you get my drift.

### EDIT

After reading through your question one more time, I realized that you're using `@model` on the parent `cshtml`, not on the AJAX-ed `cshtml`. While that can work, I have two concerns with that:

1. `@model` is not going to effect on your AJAX data. Utterly useless. Something to consider.
2. Secondly, and in conjunction with the first point, it sounds like you have two separate pieces of logic that are managing your data. One, being the Razor model-binding (which generates, I think, your initial layout), and two, being the AJAX call and the jQuery responsible for formatting your data. I'd suggest you stick with only one, but then again, that's dependent on use case as well to some extent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Richard. That is the idea model populates the grid on the page load. Jquery is used to populate a div under the grid without refreshing the grid..I can't use the same "@model" again to bind the content under the grid...unless I should just use straightforward jquery to populate and interact with the page. I ask myself why the heck am I using @model to bind a grid when I can use jquery, html straightout...

Comment: You can use `@model` like I thought you were using at first --- the action you're calling using AJAX can generate a `cshtml` view that your script can just slap onto the page. **That** `cshtml` can have a `@model` binding.

Comment: Richard - is there a sample of what you mentioned anywhere that I can study?

Comment: I don't have any in mind or ready right now, but I'll do my best to get back to you on that.